# Android proper way to handle user pressing back button

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm trying to properly handle the user pressing the back button but with no success.

After pressing an image in the main `activity`, a `fragment` is created and an `listview` with items is shown. The user now selects one of those items and a new `query` is performed populating the `listview`with another set of items. Now, after selecting an item, a new `fragment` is created showing the info of the last item the user select. Now, I pretend, if the user presses the back button, the previous `listview` is shown. Pressing again will show him the initial `listview`. I've managed to achieve the first part of the first back press but making the second back press I'm going to the main activity instead of showing the first `listview`.

This is the code after the main `activity` for handling fragments

```
public class Fragments extends ActionBarActivity implements QueryFragment.OnQuerySelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragments);
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentsboth) != null) {
            numberOfPanes = 1;
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
            QueryFragment firstFragment = new QueryFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentsboth, firstFragment).commit();
        } else if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            numberOfPanes = 2;
            QueryFragment firstFragment = new QueryFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_one, firstFragment).commit();

            Infodata secondFragment = new Infodata();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_two, secondFragment).commit();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Bundle itemSelectedData) {
        View rightLayout = findViewById(R.id.fragment_two);
        if (rightLayout != null) {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_two) instanceof Infodata) {
                Infodata itemDataFragment = (Infodata) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_two);
                itemDataFragment.populateLayoutWithData(2, itemSelectedData);
            } else {
                Infodata secondFragment = new Infodata();
                secondFragment.setArguments(itemSelectedData);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_two, secondFragment).commit();
            }
        } else {
            Infodata newFragment = new Infodata();
            newFragment.setArguments(itemSelectedData);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentsboth, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code that shows the fragment with the `listviews`.

```
public class QueryFragment extends ListFragment {
    public interface OnQuerySelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(Bundle itemSelectedData);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activityContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        if (operation == 0) {
            layoutToShow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.querylist, container, false);
            if (groupName == null) { //Performs the first initial query
                groupQuery = true;
                groupsLayout(layoutToShow, 0);
            } else { 
                groupsLayout(layoutToShow, 1); //Comes here after the first back press
                hasPerformedGroupSearch = true;
            }
        } 
        return layoutToShow;
    }
    private void groupsLayout(View layout, int step) {
        if (step == 0) {
            //Code for performing the first query
        } else if (step == 1) { 
            //Code for performing the second query
        }
        cursorAdapter = new QueryAdapter(getActivity(), query, "");
        listContent.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        listContent.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Bundle itemData = new Bundle();

        if (groupQuery) { //Gets the data from the first query
            Cursor grupo = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
            groupId = grupo.getLong(0);
            groupName = grupo.getString(1);
            groupQuery = false;
            groupsLayout(layoutToShow, 1); // Shows the data of the second query
        } else {
            //Puts the data of the second query in the bundle itemData
            mCallback.onItemSelected(itemData);
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the state of your app in some kind of static variable. Maybe an `enum`. Then override your Activities' `onBackPressed()` and maybe create something like this:

```
@Override
pulic void onBackPressed () {
    if (state == State.idle) {
        super.onBackPressed ();
    else {
        // You can customize from now on...
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the name of the method is "onBackPressed" and not "onBackButtonPressed"

Comment: @TorhanBartel Sorry for the late feedback. Thanks. That solved my problem.